# Converting a date from one language to another

Tags: javascript, date, locale, momentjs

I have a date in Thai as:

```
31มี.ค.2017, 16:56:51
```

which translates to

```
Mar 31, 2017, 16:56:51
```

using google translate. Is there a way, I could do this using momentjs locale support? If not, is there any other way out?

Comment: Language != locale. A Thai person in New York may want their dates presented in the Thai *language* but using the timezone associated with the America/New_York *locale*. ;-)

Comment: @RobG Okay. Could you explain this with an answer? With reference to currently accepted answer, what does it imply when we write `m.locale('en')` ?

Comment: It means that the people who write ECMA-402 misused the term "locale" for the language parameter (it accepts a language code, not a locality). That misuse has subsequently been continued by others, such as those writing libraries like moment.js that, I guess, want to be consistent with the specification's terminology (a bad decision in my view). But that doesn't mean you have to follow suit in the title of your question. ;-)

Comment: @RobG Okay edited the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Momentjs suports i18n and supports Thai [th] locale, you can parse your input using [`moment(String, String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

Then you can use [`locale()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/instance-locale/) and [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) to show the value using english locale.

Here a working sample:

```js
var m = moment('31มี.ค.2017, 16:56:51', 'DDMMMMYYYY, HH:mm:ss', 'th');
console.log(m.locale('en').format('MMM DD, YYYY, HH:mm:ss')); // Mar 31, 2017, 16:56:51
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Amazing. I thought of using a translator API but remain convinced that `momentjs` will definitely have a solution.